# SEVERE: Unhandled exception with JavaFX + Vert.x + REST

Tags: java, javafx, vert.x-webclient

Situation: I updated my IDE (Eclipse IDE 2020-6 to 2020-9) and the request to my web service stopped working with the following error:

```
sep. 19, 2020 7:09:23 A. M. io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at model.Concepto.<init>(Concepto.java:23)
    at consumer.ConceptoAccess.lambda$getConceptos$0(ConceptoAccess.java:31)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at consumer.ConceptoAccess.lambda$getConceptos$1(ConceptoAccess.java:28)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.handleDispatchResponse(HttpContext.java:313)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.execute(HttpContext.java:300)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.HttpContext.next(HttpContext.java:275)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.predicate.PredicateInterceptor.handle(PredicateInterceptor.java:69)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.client.impl.predicate.PredicateInterceptor.handle(PredicateInterceptor.java:32)
```

This is my ***line 23*** in Concepto.java in package "model":

```
package model;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Concepto {
    
    private IntegerProperty idconcepto;
    private StringProperty descripcion;
    
    public Concepto() {
//      idconcepto = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        descripcion = new SimpleStringProperty();
    }

    public Concepto(Integer idconcepto, String descripcion) {
//      this.idconcepto.set(idconcepto);
        this.descripcion.set(descripcion);
    }
    
    public Concepto(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion.set(descripcion);     //<----- Line 23
    }

    public StringProperty getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion.set(descripcion);
    }

    public IntegerProperty getIdconcepto() {
        return idconcepto;
    }
    
}
```

and this is ***line 31*** in ConceptoAccess.java in "consumer" package:

```
public class ConceptoAccess {
    
    private static final String HOST = "192.168.0.15";
    private static final int PORT = 8091;
    
    public static void getConceptos(ObservableList<Concepto> conceptoData) {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create(Vertx.vertx());
        client
        .get(PORT, HOST, "/api/conceptos")
        .send(ar -> {
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                conceptoData.clear();
                HttpResponse<Buffer> response = ar.result();
                response.bodyAsJsonArray().forEach(concepto -> {
                    JsonObject jo = (JsonObject) concepto;
                    conceptoData.add(new Concepto(jo.getString("descripcion")));     <---Line 31
                });
                System.out.println("Received response with status code " + response.statusCode());
                System.out.println(response.bodyAsJsonArray());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Something went wrong " + ar.cause().getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

I tested the web service and works fine:
[Tested with Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx2vO.png)

Whats' wrong? everything was working fine before the Eclipse update. I use openJDK 11 + JavaFX 14 + Vert.x 3.9.3

TIA for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just move it up to

```
private final StringProperty descripcion = new SimpleStringProperty();
```

and make it final. Remove all the other occurences of this initializer.

Answer (score 2):

You get a **NullPointerException** because you are trying to access `this.description.set` but `this.description` is *null*. You are only giving descripcion a value in the default constructor (with zero parameters) and leaving it as *null* in the others.

```
private StringProperty descripcion;

public Concepto() {
    descripcion = new SimpleStringProperty();
}

public Concepto(Integer idconcepto, String descripcion) {
    descripcion = new SimpleStringProperty(); // add this
    this.descripcion.set(descripcion);
}

public Concepto(String descripcion) {
    descripcion = new SimpleStringProperty(); // add this
    this.descripcion.set(descripcion);
}
```

Comment: OMG! What a fool I am. Thanks! all works fine...